# Test if input file is a .txt file in C

Tags: c, file, testing, text, input

Is it possible to check if the input file i would like to read text from via the stdin of the console is actually a .txt file? Something like this:

```
if(argv[1] != "*.txt")
{
  return 1;
}
```

This would be very helpful to me!
Thanks!

Comment: How about `if (strstr(argv[1], ".txt") == argv[1] + strlen(argv[1]) - 4)`, obviously after some bounds checking?

Comment: Or, `if (strlen(argv[1]) > 4 && !(strcasecmp(argv[1]+strlen(argv[1])-4, ".txt"))` for a case insensitive match. Neither method will tell if it *is* a text file, only if it has a file extension saying it is.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are looking for something like the "file" command (this is on all Mac OSX and Linux boxes) which looks at the contents of a file and tells you what sort of file it is - like a "JPG" image, or a binary executable program, or... some straightforward ASCII text in your case.

Here are two example of running it:

```
file /bin/bash
/bin/bash: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/bin/bash (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/bin/bash (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386

file /etc/passwd
/etc/passwd: ASCII English text
```

To run this from your C program, you will probably use the "system()" function

```
system("file somefile| grep text")
```

and then check if "grep" returned zero - indicating it found the word "text".

If you are on Windows, hard luck! Ooops, I mean, if you are on Windows, you will have to research a Windows equivalent.